# PyQGIS - Export multiple layouts as multiple PDF files

Tags: pyqgis, layouts, pdf

I am trying to write a script that exports all my layouts by their names as separate PDF files at specific directory.

I am beginner at programming, though.

I was trying to use 'for' loop for exporter.exportpdf() but there was a syntax error.

Here's the code

```
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
for layout in manager.printLayouts():
   string sciezka = 'file_path'
   exporter.exportToPdf(string sciezka + layout.getName(), QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

EDITV2:

saving the PDF in the project's directory

```
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
for layout in manager.printLayouts():
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    home_path = QgsProject.instance().absoluteFilePath()
    exporter.exportToPdf(home_path.format(layout.name()),
    QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

Comment: The syntax error was to try to use Java syntax in Python. You should ***always*** include the complete error in the Question body as text.

Comment: You can find the steps to this approach on Anita Graser's blog: https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-exporting-layouts/

Answer (score 1):

I read "manager.printLayouts" so I guess it's exporting cards from the print manager. if that's the case, this code exports each layout to a specific pdf

```
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
for layout in manager.printLayouts():
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    exporter.exportToPdf("F:{}.pdf".format(layout.name()),
    QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

(F: is the name of my drive)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  :)
Thank you very much

Comment: @Proelior Please mark the question as resolved